# Change detection for stream in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, buffer, angular2-changedetection

I am not able to assign a variable while a stream is being read in a component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
var fs: any = require('fs');

 @Component({
 selector: 'stream-cmp',
 templateUrl: 'app/view/stream.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app/view/stream.css'],
 })


 export class StreamCmp {

 private _anotherVariable:any = null;
 private readstream:any = null;
 private filePath:any = '/dir/file';

 public fileUpload():void {



    this.readstream =  fs.createReadStream(this.filePath, {start: 140, end:  160});

    this.readstream.on('data', function (text) {

     console.log(text);
     this.filePath = text;

    });

 }
```

Basically, this.filePath is never assigned, I never see it in the view. But console.log always works.

Do I use change detection of some sort (maybe changedetectionref since it is supposed to be fast compared to NgZone)? Since it is a stream are we getting all of it at once? Is it an asynchronous stream? Is there a property on the fs module I should call to write the data to a variable? It seems the pipe function on the fs module is meant to write to files or other streams.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `arrow` function to access current context inside function. Only changing this will not resolve your issue.

Currently you're hooked some function on `data`(custom) event for receiving a data from file stream. So in that case change detection system wouldn't come to know that the something got changed in any of component binding. That's why in this case you have to run change detection manually to update `bindings` over the page. You need to add `private ref: ChangeDetectorRef` in your component constructor which will make change detector reference object available to you. Next you will call `this.ref.detectChanges()` method to manually run zone to check & update bindings over a page.

**Code**

```
this.readstream.on('data', (text) => { // changed here to use arrow function.
 console.log(text);
 this.filePath = text; //this.filePath will be the component variable which has been declared
   this.ref.detectChanges(); //will trigger change detection system manually.
});
```

> **Change Detection**
>
> Zone is core of change detection system, it monkey patches almost all
>   the event internally like `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, DOM events, etc.
>   and when you trigger them it atomically run change detector system to
>   once those event get called. If you have any custom event which
>   doesn't fits in this list that time you have to trigger Change
>   Detection system manually to make all binding in sync.

There is couple of other way to run change detection manually, you can find it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829089/2435473) by @Mark Rajcok

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. I would have changed to arrows eventually in my own code, this is experimental right now. Arrows is a better practice, it seems like it did not solve the specific issue here.

Comment: @angularjslearner66 may I know how you are calling `fileUpload ` function?

Comment: It is being called from the view via the (click) function.

Comment: @angularjslearner66 look at the updated answer, I thing it would help you to understand why it didn't work & how you can make it working..

Comment: Thank you haha, I just figured this out on my own a few minutes ago, and then read your answer :).

Comment: @angularjslearner66 ohh.. apologies, I took too much time to edit it.. and understand the issue.. I should have catch this in initial go only. Thanks & cheers ;)

Comment: I would happily accept your answer as best answer, but don't have rights/privileges yet :(.

Comment: @angularjslearner66 I think you could accept answer, after 15 mins you should be able to see tick icon dowside of the upvote count.. Thanks for appreciation, Pankaj.